# CMake not settings compile definitions transitively

Tags: c++, cmake

I am working on a project that use `cmake` build. I have my `cmake` files like this:

```
dirA/CMakeLists.txt :

add_library(A STATIC ${SRC_FILES})
target_compile_definitions(A public -DABC)

dirB/CMakeLists.txt :

add_library(B STATIC ${SRC_FILES})
target_link_libraries(B PRIVATE A)        //-DABC is passed to B

dirC/CMakeLists.txt :

add_library(C STATIC ${SRC_FILES})
target_link_libraries(C B)                ////-DABC is not passed to C
```

I observe that flag `-DABC` is being passed to library `B` but not to library `C`. Is there a way to pass the compile definitions in `cmake` transitively?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Link A to B publicly.

```
target_link_libraries(B PUBLIC A)
```

Private linkage explicitly halts transitive propagation of properties.